# how to remove gap from generated report in php

Tags: php, sql, report

I have a generated report from sql query in php, the output is:[image]

The Query is:

> > SELECT 'S. J. & G. FAZUL ELLAHIE (PVT) LTD.' AS CompanyName,'E - 46, S.I.T.E., KARACHI - 75700' AS CompanyAddress,'admin' login_user,'Invoice_49161' selpdfFileName,'SP_DeliveryChallan' seltoprint,'crm.sjg.local' selhost,'admin' sellogin,'SI' selrptType,'false' selisTP,'Transfer to Stock' seldeliveryChallanTitle,'1494' seldocId,* FROM SP_Order(1494)

Comment: where you want remove gap ?

Comment: How is your report generated?

Comment: the gaps above the 2, 3 and 4 id in which the empty row with approx. no border is occupying the place..

Comment: Are you sure its on SQL? I think its on your PHP loop.. Recheck loop tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your consideration. I got the solution, the problem was actually in the crystal reports. It was a formatting error, the joints of lines were not connected to each other.

Thanks Again.